# Sending Data to Soap Service by SharePoint 2013 or SPD2013

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2013

I have a SOAP service that takes a USERID and a Qualification Code and returns a Boolean(true) if the User was found and the Qualification Code was added to their name.  Inside Visual Studio I had no problem writing a simple page that had 2 text boxes where I took the info from those text boxes and submitted it to the web service. I can't figure out how to do this inside SharePoint or SharePoint Designer both are 2013.  I have followed [these directions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-SOAP-service-as-a-data-source-638dd2db-e4e8-4279-809c-e9b785c36312) to add the service as a Data source but I'm unsure how to work with it.

The overall project is I have a training site and when an employee passes a test I want to pass the user and qualification to the SOAP web service to be updated in another environment.  Yes it's duplicated info but it's how the company wants it. The information in SharePoint is stored in a list.

**Edit**
So I think I have to do it in ParameterBindings.  If I just change the location to Controls(textboxid) I'm assuming this will call the web service with whatever is in these text boxes but so far it's not.

```
<parameterbindings>
        <ParameterBinding Name="userID" Location="Control(UserIDTB)" DefaultValue="domain\user"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="qualificationCode" Location="Control(QualCode)" DefaultValue="PIT"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_nextpagedata" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    </parameterbindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

So for me I couldn't figure out or maybe it's not possible to do this in SharePoint Designer. I had to create an Event Receiver inside Visual Studio that connects to SOAP service then sends Data from my list to that service. The completed code is below. I doubt I need all the additions at the top but I just left them as it was working.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

namespace CompletedTraining.TrainingCompleteListener
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class TrainingCompleteListener : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            //Item was just added to the list
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    //get the item that was just added
                    SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;
                    //create a new connection to the NavSoapService
                    NAVSoapService.EmployeeQualificationMgt service = new NAVSoapService.EmployeeQualificationMgt();
                    //Use the default credentials for this service
                    service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    //convert the Name field from the list to a string we'll use to pass to the NavSoapService. We need the username(superb\user) instead of just name(first last) the next 3 lines do this conversion
                    string nameField = currentItem["Name"].ToString();
                    SPFieldUserValue userField = (SPFieldUserValue)currentItem.Fields["Name"].GetFieldValue(nameField);
                    SPUser user = userField.User;
                    //Once we have user id we need to get their login name(superb\user) and remove the 7 junk characters to the left
                    string loginName = (user.LoginName).Substring(7);
                    //Call the service with the login name and the Qualification code store the result in the result variable.
                    bool result = service.AddEmployeeQualification(loginName, (string)currentItem["Qualification Code"]);
                    //write the result in the Uploaded to NAV column
                    currentItem["Uploaded to NAV"] = result;
                    //update the current item in the list.
                    currentItem.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Two other items needed and 1 is in your project you need to connect to the Web Service and 2 is to change the Elements.xml file if you only want this to have an affect on 1 list.

```
<!--<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">-->
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Completed Training">
```